# why ng-content not working in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using `ng-content` in my demo but my `innerHTML` is not displayed.why is inner content not displayed?

here is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lav42u

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
  <h4 class="card-title">
    <ng-content select=".setup"></ng-content>
  </h4>
  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
```

Comment: Why do you have `select=".setup"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your `select` is looking for an element which has the class `setup` and will not project any other element unless it answers that condition. You must remove the `select=".setup"` in order for the `<p>` element inside of `<hello>` in the `AppComponent` to be projected, or add the `setup` class to that element.

[image]